# jQuery 1.9 checkbox count

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have some old jQuery code from 1.6 that works perfectly but I'm currently redoing the website and upgraded to 1.9.1 jQuery and my old code does not work.

```
$("input[type=checkbox][name=compare[]]").click(function() {    
    var bol = $("input[type=checkbox][name=compare[]]:checked").length >= 5;     
    $("input[type=checkbox][name=compare[]]").not(":checked").attr("disabled",bol); 
    $(this).closest("tr").toggleClass("marked", this.checked);
});
```

I have table rows with a single checkbox with the value of the row, if checked it pushes the row id into an array so I can work else where with it. It also only allows up to 5 checkboxs to be active at once and disables the rest so they can't be checked (yes I know these can be done via DOM but it's checked in PHP before any processing). It would also apply the class marked which is just a darker bg to help to make it easier to read.

I receive the following error in the javascript console in chrome on load

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input[type=checkbox][name=compare[]]
```

At the time the code was more of a hack job and surprised my self that it even worked (lol).

The following code would select the checked checkboxs and put the value into array so I could json' it off via ajax.

```
$("input[type=checkbox][name=compare[]]:checked").each(function() {
        data['id[]'].push($(this).val());
    });
```

I've started to rewrite it but hit a problem when trying to give each checkbox it's own unique identifier, while before jquery would do it self.

.compare_check is class of the checkbox

```
$('.compare_check').click(function() {      
    if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
                 // do some work on
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't know how it relates, but I'd suggest to surround attribute values with quotes in the selector: `$("input[type='checkbox'][name='compare[]']:checked")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the value for the attribute you want to check in double quotes, so you'd have:

```
$('input[type=checkbox][name="compare[]"]')
```

rather than

```
$("input[type=checkbox][name=compare[]]")
```

Alternatively you can use `\\` to escape the `[` and `]` in the attribute name:

```
$("input[type=checkbox][name=compare\\[\\]]")
```

You should probably also be using `.prop()`, rather than `.attr()`, to set the elements as disabled.

Comment: Thanks that got it, couldn't believe it was as easy as escaping the selector value, i've also changed it to prop() too.  :)